# How can I get data in my JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data are:

```
{   "Users" : {
    "Info" : {
      "GLjqemedMVRK1mgZVpPaIOuMuNx1" : {
        "adi" : "e e",
        "aracMarkasi" : "HONDA",
        "aracModeli" : "Civic",
        "eposta" : "a@a.co",
        "motorHacmi" : "1.6"
      },
      "SLtt56YlVsRfjrnAyBlUNdEakly2" : {
        "adi" : "e g",
        "aracMarkasi" : "SEAT",
        "aracModeli" : "Leon",
        "eposta" : "eg@gmail.com",
        "motorHacmi" : "1.4 Tsi"
      }
    }   
}
}
```

And then I retrieve data

```
let databseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://ffs.firebaseio.com/Users/Info/")
databseRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let adi = snapshot.value(forKey: "adi")
            let eposta = snapshot.value(forKey: "eposta")
            let aracMarkasi = snapshot.value(forKey: "aracMarkasi")
            let aracModeli = snapshot.value(forKey: "aracModeli")
            let motorHacmi = snapshot.value(forKey: "motorHacmi")


        })
```

It returns error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRDataSnapshot 0x78f6d5b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adi.'
```

How can I get data? Note that `GLjqemedMVRK1mgZVpPaIOuMuNx1` and `SLtt56YlVsRfjrnAyBlUNdEakly2` are users `uid`.

Comment: output of `print(snapshot)` is?

Comment: snapshot : Snap (GLjqemedMVRK1mgZVpPaIOuMuNx1) {
    adi = "e e";
    aracMarkasi = HONDA;
    aracModeli = Civic;
    eposta = "a@a.co";
    motorHacmi = "1.6";
}

@Mr.UB

Answer (score 2):

Try :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/Info").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {(snap) in

        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict{

                print(each)
                let adi = each.value["adi"]
                let eposta = each.value["eposta"]
                let aracMarkasi = each.value["aracMarkasi"]
                let aracModeli = each.value["aracModeli"]
                let motorHacmi = each.value["motorHacmi"]

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: And how can i use adi,soyadi, etc. out of for loop? Because all variables fill after for each end. @Dravidian

Comment: Use arrays, append those values... Accept and upvote this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding